# Google 2 factor authentication on Ec2?

Tags: security, ssh, amazon-ec2, authentication, public-key

I have set up google two factor authentication on my local machine. So when I do :

```
ssh localhost
```

I need to verify the code along with password. But when I try to connect to my Ec2 instance like so :

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@x.x.x.x.x
```

It just asks for the password (here is no second factor). How could I provide the password along with the verify code that I see in my google app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you are using key-based authentication (the `-i mykey.pem` in your above example), ssh will bypass the PAM stack and authenticate you using only your key.  If you're being prompted for a password it is probably for the key passphrase.

If you were to connect without using a key:

```
ssh ubuntu@x.x.x.x
```

The behavior should be the same as with your initial `ssh localhost` example.

Based on your questions, you may want to spend a little time reading [some documentation](http://goo.gl/bGqx3).  That link is explicitly about Amazon EC2 instances, but there are lots of other guides out there to setting up authentication with google-authenticator.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working either. when I do `ssh ubuntu@x.x.x.x` I get `Permission denied (publickey).`!

Comment: Is your local `ssh` configured to not use password authentication?  What if you run `ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes ubuntu@x.x.x.x`?

Comment: That is because you need to use the keyfile. And you do already have some kind of two factor auth, as the keyfile is one - password is two.

Comment: If I run `ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes ubuntu@x.x.x.x` I get the same : `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: AFAIK by default the EC2 Ubuntu AMIs are configured for key based authentication only.

Comment: Take a look at your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure that both `PasswordAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` are set to `yes` (although the fact that it works from `localhost` is weird).

Comment: So I also need to install google-authenticator on Ec2? Is that so?

Comment: You need the `google-authenticator` PAM module installed wherever you expect to be authenticating with it...and you need the command line tool for generating credentials.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup 2 factor auth in this way it is a server side process, not client side. You've setup the SSH *server* component on your local machine to do 2 factor, which is why you're prompted for the additional credentials.

As the 2 factor auth doesn't depend on the client (that would add no security) you need to setup the SSH server on your EC2 instance to do 2 factor as well.

Comment: Alright, if I do this way(having installed the google authenticator in ec2 instance too): `ssh ubuntu@x.x.x.x`, its asking for the password(after verification code). What password I need to give over here? I just downloaded my key without any passwords.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't specify a password when you *created* the key pair that you're using?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I just gave a name and downloaded it!